# Why was 555489 closed?

Tags: support, reopen-request, specific-question

Why was this question: https://superuser.com/q/555489/101850 closed as duplicate of [Disable ClearType (blurry fonts) in Internet Explorer 10 on windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/506192/101850)? I have an exactly opposite problem and the answers for that question do not help me.

Answer (score 5):

Your question was closed as a duplicate because the other question has [an answer which actually answers your question](https://superuser.com/a/553816/144961).

Since enabling and disabling a feature almost always involve the same actions, it's reasonable to treat them together.

Comment: -1 ClearType is enabled systemwide. I have problems with it in IE.

Comment: That's why your question was marked as a duplicate. It explains the problem and gives you your answer.

Comment: Where is it given how to fix ClearType?

Comment: The [other answer](http://superuser.com/a/555608/144961) explains how to work around it. Did you actually read _any_ of the answers?!

Comment: This did not work. Still no cleartype.

Comment: You need to edit your question to specify exactly what you tried, then.

Comment: Edited. (8 more to go)